# Code mirror markText method using replaceWith parameter does not work

Tags: codemirror

I figured out that https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#markText is the way to render html content inside the codemirror editor. I am trying to do the same using the `replaceWith` option and it doesn't seem to reflect in the editor.

For instance, I want {{dynamic.first_name}} to be transformed into
`<span><span>dynamic</span><span>first_name</span></span>` and rendered as html so that it is styled in a certain manner. For achieving this I did the following:

```
let node = `<span><span>dynamic</span><span>first_name</span></span>`;
codemirror.markText(
from,
to,
{ replaceWith: node }
);
```

But there is no change. Editor still displays {{dynamic.first_name}}

Answer (score 0):

You need to define where (line and character) the widget will be inserted, and `let node` needs to be a dom element.

```
let node = $(`<span><span>dynamic</span><span>first_name</span></span>`)[0];

codemirror.markText( { line: 1, ch: 0 }, { line: 1, ch: 1 }, {replacedWith: node} );
```